# no sheets visible - Macro enabled excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that I inherited that has 5 worksheets but none of them are visible and it's always been like this since I got it. I've tried changing the sheet properties in the VBA editor to visible (was to begin with but I toggled between hidden and back to visible).

The unhide option (in the main excel program) isn't available, and the arrange all option isn't available.

I've ran some VBA to hide and unhide all sheets and this hasn't worked either.

does anybody have any other suggestions?

thanks
Gary

Comment: How about disabling macro execution, then trying to make `Visible = xlSheetVisible` for each Sheet object in the Visual Basic Editor (via Properties window)? There might be some code that hides them back each time you modify the sheet object; disabling VBA execution might help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the property `Visible` of your worksheets in VBA editor. If it has value `2 - xlSheetVeryHidden`, then you cannot unhide it from normal Excel window. Change it to `-1 - xlSheetVisible`.

Comment: I've tried it already, they were -1 - xlSheetVisible to begin with but I switched then to 0 - xlSheetHidden and back

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that the previous user had Excel spread across two monitors (and sized to whatever that intermediate state is called) and the worksheets drug off to the side, where you now can't see them. If so, this should fix it:

```
Sub test()
Dim wn As Excel.Window 

For Each wn In ThisWorkbook.Windows 
    wn.WindowState = xlMaximized 
Next wn 
End Sub
```

Note that Excel requires that you always have at least one worksheet visible. If you try to hide the last one it will squawk at you.

Comment: I've tried that code and it didn't work. I'd also previously tried to recreate what he has done but can't - I get the error you mention, I was hoping that if I could find out how to recreate it then I'd also find out how to undo it.